# How do I create a batch script creates certain registry entries in all subfolders

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, windows-registry

I was reading this on the web:

> 1. Press Windows Key + R, type "regedit" in the box, then press enter.
> 2. Go to this path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces
> 3. Repeat steps 4 and 5 for all folders under "Interfaces" (You can have from 1-100 folders, i had 14)
> 4. Create two new registry keys called "TcpAckFrequency" and "TCPNoDelay" (Right click on an empty scace, go to "New" and select
>      DWORD (32-bit) Value)

How do I create a batch script that goes through all the folders in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces` and adds the two DWORD entries of `"TcpAckFrequency" and "TCPNoDelay"`?

I'm assuming the `FOR` command is used but I just don't know how to  do it.

Edit: I'd also like to know the code needed to go through and delete all those keys from the folders.

Comment: What did you actually try out to complete your request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do I create a batch script that:

> goes through all the folders in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces` and adds the two `DWORD` entries of `TcpAckFrequency` and `TCPNoDelay`?
>
> I'd also like to know the code needed to go through and delete all those keys from the folders.

**Warning**:

- The instructions below contain steps that tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly.
- Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs.
- For more information see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756)

---

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem get the keys
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces`) do (
  rem add the values
  reg add %%i /v "TcpAckFrequency" /d "1" /t REG_DWORD
  reg add %%i /v "TCPNoDelay" /d "1" /t REG_DWORD
  )
rem get the keys
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces`) do (
  rem delete the values
  echo delete %%i /v "TcpAckFrequency" /f
  echo delete %%i /v "TCPNoDelay" /f
  )
endlocal
```

Note:

- Replace the `1` in `/d "1"` with whatever value is appropriate for your use case.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [reg](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) - Read, Set or Delete registry keys and values, save and restore from a .REG file.